# add class to html inside backtick base on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class, conditional-operator

i want to add class with the name -selected using ternaryoperator to my div with classname poll__option if the variable selectd equal to item.labe

```
   for (const item of data) {
      const template = document.createElement("template");
      const fragment = template.content;
      template.innerHTML = `
        <div class="poll__option">
      <div class="poll__option-fill"></div>
      <div class="poll__option-info">
        <span class="poll__label">${item.label}</span>
        <span class="poll__percentage">${item.percentege}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
    }
```

I expect that if selected==item.label it will add class with name -selected to my div

Comment: You can use `?:` inside `${ }`  eg: `var x=1; var s=\`Test${x===1?"":"s"}\`;console.log(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable and replace it in the template

```
for (const item of data) {
  const template = document.createElement("template");
  const fragment = template.content;
  const myClass = selected==item.label ? 'poll__option-selected' : 'poll__option';
  template.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${myClass}">
      <div class="poll__option-fill"></div>
      <div class="poll__option-info">
        <span class="poll__label">${item.label}</span>
        <span class="poll__percentage">${item.percentege}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}
```